# How to achieve equal height of inner divs and float:left at the same time?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I had four containers with four inner divs, floated left with auto height.

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="head">
        Heading text
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        Image
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet.
    </div>
    <div class="link"><a href="#">Link text</a></div>
```

```
.box{
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
}
```

Complete jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/H8w32/

To make the inner divs height the same througout all of the four containers, I changed the floated layout, and used display:table instead.

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row head">
        <div class="cell">Heading text</div>
        <div class="cell">Here is a lot longer heading text to examplify</div>
        <div class="cell">Heading text</div>
        <div class="cell">Heading text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row image">
        <div class="cell">Image</div>
        <div class="cell">Image</div>
        <div class="cell">Image</div>
        <div class="cell">Image</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row text">
        <div class="cell">Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet.</div>
        <div class="cell">Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet.</div>
        <div class="cell">Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Integer posuere erat a ante. Dapibus posuere velit aliquet.</div>
        <div class="cell">Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row link">
        <div class="cell"><a href="#">Link text</a></div>
        <div class="cell"><a href="#">Link text</a></div>
        <div class="cell"><a href="#">Link text</a></div>
        <div class="cell"><a href="#">Link text</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

-

```
.table{
display: table;
}

.row{
    display: table-row;
}

.cell{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 150px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wh7Pm/1/

This looks exactly like I wanted it to. But now I lost the perks from using float, specifically the ability to add more containers and that they automatically got pushed in to the next "row", or that they get pushed to a new row if the viewport is too small to fit them. The containers are added to the same "row" if I add more containers to my display:table layout.

Is this possible to solve? I want the behaviour from both display:table (equal height of heading divs and text divs) and float:left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible currently without using javascript to set heights. You may want to look into the spec for CSS flexible boxes, which is the real CSS-only solution to this problem.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes

Adoption of flexbox is still in the early stages, but if you're building a cutting edge app that targets mostly modern browsers, you may be able to get away with it.

Comment: That's what I suspected. I need to support IE8 so flexbox is unfortunately not an alternative. I'll have to think about what to do about this, I'll definately try the js alternative. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'll share with you a trick I sometimes use to fake the effect of equal height columns.

Often the design feature that indicates an equal height column is a border separating each column. You can't simply put border-left on each element as each one has a different height. But you can put left AND right borders on each element and allow them to overlap using negative margins (or positioning).